# Как вытащить список методов, которые есть в либе?

Tags: python, lib

Есть внешняя dll. Подключаю её при помощи ctypes. Подскажите, как вытащить список методов которые есть в либе.

```
from ctypes import *
libc = CDLL("lib.dll")
```

в питоне новичок.

Comment: Про библиотеки не знаю, но список методов объекта можно посмотреть через

    dir(object)

Если и не покажет список методов самой библиотеки, то может быть подскажет какой метод вызвать, чтобы этот список получить)

Comment: [Здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891493/list-exported-functions-from-dll-with-ctypes) говорят, что нельзя...

`dir` ничего хорошего не показывает(

UPD: Может [это](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/143384/get-dll-methodsedited) то, что надо (последний комментарий)?

Comment: @BOPOH Второй вариант вроде как работает, вывело кучу слов, которые похожи на названия методов. Буду дальше изучать.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ из комментария @BOPOH на вопрос:

```
import os, pefile

dll = 'C:\Windows\system32\comdlg32.dll'
pe = pefile.PE(dll)
"""
pefile module can be downloaded at:
http://code.google.com/p/pefile/
"""
print "DLL IMPORT Reading (DLL dependencies) for: " + os.path.basename(dll)
for entry in pe.DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT:
    print entry.dll

    for imp in entry.imports:
        print '\t', hex(imp.address), imp.name

print("DLL EXPORT Reading:" + os.path.basename(dll))
for exp in pe.DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT.symbols:
    print hex(pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.ImageBase + exp.address), exp.name, exp.ordinal

# pe.dump_info()
```